_AutomationInstance data view is not returning right data
can anyone lend me a hand?
I'm having trouble retrieving data about my automations using the data view _AutomationInstance. Automation Studio is returning incorrect data for certain automations in terms of the time they ran.
I don't think there's an issue with my query because some of the time data is accurate, but there are inconsistencies, as I mentioned earlier.
Here's the query I ran in Query Studio:
SELECT  
    a.AutomationName,
    a.AutomationCustomerKey,
    CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(a.AutomationInstanceStartTime_UTC, DATEPART(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS StartDate,
    CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(a.AutomationInstanceEndTime_UTC, DATEPART(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS Enddate,
    DATEPART(HOUR, SWITCHOFFSET(a.AutomationInstanceStartTime_UTC, DATEPART(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS Startime,
    DATEPART(HOUR, SWITCHOFFSET(a.AutomationInstanceEndTime_UTC, DATEPART(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS EndTime,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.AutomationInstanceStartTime_UTC, a.AutomationInstanceEndTime_UTC) AS ExecutionMin
FROM 
    [_AutomationInstance] a 

what I need:
I need a query that shows me the name of the automation, when it starts running, when it finishes running and the average execution time. I tried to get this result with the query above.

Could it be that Data View is simply not bringing you the latest data about automations' runs?
